# Search a text in a file in ubuntu and then print upto n no of lines thereafter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have a log file on the server which I want to check for logs but its pretty huge. I suspect there are some errors after the line

`at com.pckname.Classname.methodname(Classname.java:296)`

I want to write a serach command from ubuntu's command line that gets n no of lines after finding the line no of the text written above.

Anyone has any ideas ?

I tried 'grep "search-string" ' but that would obviously not solve the purpose. By the above command I know something is wrong but if I get the output in the file upto a few lines after that I would know exactly WHAT is the problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep 'your_search_string' --after-context=N your_log_file
```